# Basic MVC patten doen't work

Tags: php, oop

I have run following code but  nothing happened

```
<?php
class Model
{
    public $string;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = 'MVC + PHP = Awesome, click here';
    }

}

class Controller
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function clicked() {
        $this->model->string = 'Updated Data, thanks to MVC and PHP!';
    }
}

class View
{
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller,$model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output() {
        return '<p><a href="index.php?action=clicked"' . $this->model->string . "</a></p>";
    }
}


$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);



if (isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {

    $controller->{$_GET['action']}();
}

echo $view->output();

?>
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `E_DOESNT_WORK` is not a known PHP error type.

Answer (score 2):

You had a typo in this line.. The `<a>` tag was not closed and that's why you were not able to see the text.

#### The fixed code..

```
 public function output() {
        return '<p><a href="index.php?action=clicked">' . $this->model->string . "</a></p>";
    }
```

Comment: How awesome.How do you looking that kind of typo errors deeply "?

Comment: @samitha, I ran your code and saw a blank output and inspected the source :) , so I came to know that your code was actually running right.

Comment: ok.Thank you brother.I really appreciated your contribution on this